# jQuery UI, setting two handles calling only one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a bit of trouble using the slider in the jQuery UI API.

I'm using a slider that has two handles, and I want to change them both manually. I would go about doing this in two steps, one for each handle;

```
$('#slider-range').slider('values', 0, 1000);
$('#slider-range').slider('values', 1, 2000);
```

The problem with this is that each function calls the `change event` in the `slider`. Is there a way to do this with only one function call? What annoys me the most is that I think I did it before, but that same code isn't doing it now. It's actually not doing anything.

```
$('#slider-range').slider('option', 'values', [1000, 2000]);
```

_L

Comment: Just curious, have you tried `$('#slider-range').slider('option',  { values: [1000, 2000] });`?

Answer (score -1):

Your code is according to the jQuery docs

```
 $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "values", [1,5,9] );
```

so I guess this is just due to jQuery being a crappy foundation to build on top..

Comment: But why three values in that array? I can't get my head around it, and it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Downvote for 'jquery is a crappy foundation'. Not helpful at all.